# Play a sequence of files using VLCJ

Tags: java, event-listener, vlcj

First time using VLCJ. I got it to play one file, but I need to play multiple files in succession.
I realize there is an EventListener for mediaEnded, but I can't figure out how to use it... I'm kinda new to Java, and it's the first time I'm using a GUI at all.
I think I just need help setting up the listener and I can hook it up to my program by myself. Any help would be appreciated.
If it helps, I'm using an EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent to play the files.
Thank you

Comment: It will help others a lot if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm going to close this question. I found the solution in an VLCJ example :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution in a VLCJ example

public class TestMediaListEmbeddedPlayer extends VlcjTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
    CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);

    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

    MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaListPlayer();

    mediaListPlayer.addMediaListPlayerEventListener(new MediaListPlayerEventAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void nextItem(MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer, libvlc_media_t item, String itemMrl) {
            System.out.println("nextItem()");
        }
    });

    mediaListPlayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer); // <--- Important, associate the media player with the media list player

    JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    cp.setBackground(Color.black);
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("vlcj embedded media list player test");
    f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(TestMediaListEmbeddedPlayer.class.getResource("/icons/vlcj-logo.png")).getImage());
    f.setContentPane(cp);
    f.setSize(800, 600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    MediaList mediaList = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaList();
    String[] options = {};
    mediaList.addMedia("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\videoplayback1.mp4", options);
    mediaList.addMedia("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\videoplayback2.mp4", options);

    mediaListPlayer.setMediaList(mediaList);
    mediaListPlayer.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);

    mediaListPlayer.play();

    // This looping is just for purposes of demonstration, ordinarily you would
    // not do this of course
    for(;;) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        mediaPlayer.setChapter(3);

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        mediaListPlayer.playNext();
    }

    //    mediaList.release();
    //    mediaListPlayer.release();
    //    mediaPlayer.release();
    //    mediaPlayerFactory.release();
}
```

}